# How to find width of (1D discrete) Gaussian Kernel for a certain sigma?

Tags: image-processing, gaussian

Is there a rule of thumb or mathematical equation that tells me how wide my (1D discrete) Gaussian Kernel should be for a certain sigma?

Lets say, I choose a sigma of 1.87, should my kernel be 5 values/steps/pixels wide, 7 oder rather 25 in order to perform standardized image smoothing? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a threshold that you consider ignorable, like `T = 0.01`. Then solve `exp(-x^2/(2s^2)) / sqrt(2pi s^2) < T`:

`|x| < s sqrt(-2 ln(sqrt(2pi s^2) T))`

The right hand side gives you the width. For `s = 1.87` and `T = 0.01`, this gives you a width of 4 pixels.